# how to show only two rows of data in the listview of android

Tags: android, listview

i am getting problem as i have some data in a database tabel file i am successfully able to show data into it but .as the data is going bigger the list view item data is also increasing .in need to show only 2 lines of data into it so that all the data i can show sufficiently .

This is the image of the list view  [image]

Please help me achieving this .
this is the code i am writing in main Activity class

```
        ArrayList<String> results = myDbHelper.getNamesArray(MY_DATABASE_TABLE); 
        //setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, COUNTRIES));
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
        this.setTitleColor(Color.BLACK);
        ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        lv.setCacheColorHint(0);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

Thanks in advance.
Moqthar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a [custom row view](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) with a TextView in it.
Here you can set your TextView to 2 lines with [android:lines](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3alines)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use custom layout for your listview item. Take TextView and make advantage of ellipsize and singleLine properties.And Use `android:maxLines=2` in textview...